# Get fractional part of a number using IEEE754

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, ieee-754

I have a code that works using loop but it's bad imo, because can be simplified. I mean this loop:

```
    private static long GetFract(double d)
    {
        if (d < 0)
            return GetFract(-d);
        d -= Math.Truncate(d);
        long result = 0;
        checked
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    d *= 10;
                    long tmp = (long)d;
                    if (Math.Abs(tmp - d) < double.Epsilon)
                        return tmp;
                    result = tmp;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

expected results: `2.3333` -> `3333`

so can we use `IEEE754` to get a fractional part of a number without using `ToString()`, `Split()` and other functions, using just FP and integer math? I mean some bit magic:

```
    private static unsafe long GetFract(double d)
    {
        if (d < 0)
            return GetFract(-d);
        d -= Math.Truncate(d);
        const long mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF; //some magic const here
        long x = *((long*) &d);
        return x & mask;
    }
```

we assume that d is always in [0..1], long and double are 8 bytes both

Comment: Sure, change the exponent after shifting out the left part...

Comment: You solved the title question in the first three lines, no loop.  Your more complicated problem (which the comments don't really address) is finding a good approximation using a base-10 denominator.  There's no direct way to do that, although you might use a binary loop instead of linear search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence of bits representing the number `3333` is not found in the IEEE 754 representation of `2.3333`, nor `0.3333`, because IEEE 754 uses a binary exponent, not decimal.

That is, you are looking for the numerator in `3333 / 10000` but the internal representation is (when converted to decimal) `6004199023210345 / 18014398509481984` (that denominator is 2<sup>54</sup>)

There's no bit hack that will extract data that isn't there in the first place.